# Differences of 2 methods of outputting a response in Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, http-headers, response

There are 2 methods of outputting a response from Controller in Laravel.  I want to know the advantages, disadvantages (pros and cons), and differences between using these 2 methods.  Also, any effects on cookies, session, headers?

The reasons do not specifically need to be for Laravel, it could be for PHP generally.  But I need the info to ensure my implementation is flawless.

I'm also looking into doing the best practices.

**METHOD A:**

```
return response('Hello World');
```

**METHOD B:**

```
response('Hello World')->send();
exit;
```

**From what I understand at the moment.**

- Method A does not output the response immediately, and will let it return first, and then build the response some time later (during some Laravel post processing work.)
- Method B makes the output immediately.
- Method B makes use of exit;
- Method B works in the constructor method, while Method A does not.

**My Questions**

1. For Method A, specifically, what type of post processing does Laravel do after returning something in controller?  By knowing specifically what's done after returning the response, I may know the consequences and know which method is more suitable for me.
2. Any problems with outputting immediately for Method B?  Any Cons?
3. Any disadvantages of using exit?  Or is it a bad practice, and why?

Thanks!

Comment: Method A makes it clear that the controller action is returning something, which it should. It's also more concise than Method B.

Comment: Are there any other comments about this?  Actually, I'm sort of forced into the corner to use Method B, because of Laravel's limitation.  I tried to return a class library with a __toString() method, thinking that it will output my response correctly.  But Laravel uses my string output, and encapsulates an extra layer of HTTP wrapper around it, making my response invalid.

Comment: That's the default implementation. Check the [`prepareResponse()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1037) method of the `Illuminate\Routing\Router`. It wraps the return value of the controller with `Illuminate\Http\Response` if it is not an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` or `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface`.

Comment: Yeah I did notice that.  I was wondering if I could override its default, or something avoid using it.

Comment: Why would you want that by the way? How about using `after middlewares` to modify the response?

Comment: I actually want to keep my dependency to Laravel minimal, and having a ResponseWrapper of my own would make things much easier for future in case I'm switching over a FW.  I've learnt my lesson switching from CI to Laravel.  Middlewares are the same, and just wondering why we would have to run "after middlewares" when I've already decided my output.  Seems like CI and Symfony outputs immediately, so this was one thing I didn't really quite get with Laravel, or maybe I don't know well enough.